# Rendering content element by Uid

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to render a content element only by having it's Uid.
It's supposed to be the login form of fe_login placed directly into a navigation Overlay.

I tried saving the element into a variable by using CONTENT. It did not work, obviously.
But I'm not even sure if I used used the correct syntax.

```
page.10.variables.contentLogin = CONTENT
page.10.variables.contentLogin {
    table = tt_content
    select.where {
        uidInList = 32
        pidInList = 0
    } 
}
```

And the same for lib.loginContent.

Added both respectively with

```html
{contentLogin -> f:format.raw()}
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginContent"/>
```

But this only renders the object I already have on this page and not the element I am looking for globally.

**EDIT:** I found the solution. See my own answer.

Comment: I wrote a blog article some time ago about it: https://brot.krue.ml/render-typo3-content-element-in-fluid-template/

Comment: @Chris sadly the link is broken. Can you check that again?

Comment: The link works perfectly.

Comment: I can not reach the website via Desktop PC but I can reach it when I'm using mobile data and going in through my phone. Interesting. I'll see into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem in my code is the select.where statement.

The working code is:

```
lib.loginContent = CONTENT
lib.loginContent {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        uidInList.field = myUid
        pidInList = 0
    } 
}
```

and in HTML

```html
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginContent" data="{myUid: 32}"/>
```

The change I made was to just delete the ".where" from the select.
After checking the Doc again and again I finally realized my mistake. I hope other people will find this question and answer useful as I did not find anything on the internet that could help me with the problem.

Code for static content element:

```
lib.foo = CONTENT
lib.foo {
    #tt_content is the default table. I just like to write down where Im looking for it
    table = tt_content
    select {
        uidInList.field = Your ContentElement ID goes here!
        pidInList = 0
    }
}
```

---

```html
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginContent">
```

That's it. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The `f:cObject`-viewhelper has a [`data`-attribute](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/11.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html#data) for passing any data to the called TypoScript-object. The passed data is accessible as fields in TypoScript:

The Fluid part:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loginContent" data="{myUid: 123}"/>
```

And in TypoScript:

```
lib.loginContent = CONTENT
lib.loginContent {
    table = tt_content
    select.where {
        uidInList.field = myUid
        pidInList = 0
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sadly this still only shows the already existing elements of that page.

Comment: Pretty sure, you are struggling because of `pidInList`. Is '0' the correct pid for the desired element? `pidInList` is required and must match, but the are some special values, too: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Select.html#pidinlist

Comment: as it is written in the Docs 0 is a special value which disables the pidInList parameter enabling searching on all parent objects. In my own answer you can see the working code.

Comment: yes, in "where" are no parameters, but it should be a string that can be added to an SQL statement, if it's used. It can be used to restrict search for a special "colPos" or an own plugin only.